# How to efficiently fill a np.zeros with ones in a "thermometric" way?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I'm really interested is in a function `foo` such that it fills up a size-n `np.zeros` or something equivalent with ones based on a number `x` between 0 and 1.

**Example:**

```
>>> foo(1, 3)
array([1., 1., 1.])
>>> foo(0, 3)
array([0., 0., 0.])
>>> foo(.6, 3)
array([1., 1., 0.])
>>> foo(.3, 3)
array([1., 0., 0.])
```

I've actually done that in the for-loop manner, which showed up more expensive than I desired.

Comment: randomly or blockwise?

Comment: What's a “thermometric” way? Could you share your loopy version?

Comment: Blockwise, filling from left to right!

Comment: I meant "thermometric" by the way the array is filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way assuming I got the meaning of "thermometric" way from the samples -

```
def foo(a,b):
    out = np.zeros(b)
    out[:int(np.ceil(b*a))] = 1
    return out
```

One-liner with `broadcasted comparison` -

```
def foo(a,b):
    return (np.arange(b) < b*a).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: foo(1,3)
Out[107]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])

In [108]: foo(0,3)
Out[108]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])

In [109]: foo(0.6,3)
Out[109]: array([ 1.,  1.,  0.])

In [110]: foo(0.3,3)
Out[110]: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.])
```

Comment: I think that this np.ceil is not necessary, although the one-liner is very instersting!

Comment: Any idea on timeit/efficiency of those two ways?

Comment: @Pedro I thought it was, because without it, you would have : `foo(0.3,3) = array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])`, won't it? That seems to be different from your expected one in the samples.

Comment: That's an interesting issue, i thought it as below .33 and above zero for the first position, between .33 and .66 for the next one and above .66 for the third. Thats somehow arbitrary I guess, as to fit a specific problem. I was more intersted in the mechanics of the array-filling.

Comment: @Pedro On timings first one should be more efficient as its just slicing and assigning after initialization, whereas the second needs to create the range array.

Answer (score 1):

Randomly:

```
def foo(p, n):
    return np.random.choice(2, (n,), p = [p-1, p])
```

blockwise:

```
def foo(p, n):
    out = np.zeros(n)
    out[:int(p*n)] = 1
    return out
```